# IErrorInfo.GetDescription Failed With E_FAIL(0x80004005). [Reserved Word For Access]

Tags: vb.net, connection, oledb, using

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Click
    cmd2 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select [Member_Id] From Member_Details  EXCEPT select [M_Ids] from Books_Issue", cn)
    '  cmd2 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(" Select Member_Id From Member_Details LEFT JOIN Books_Issue ON Member_Id =M_Ids Where ((M_Ids) Is Null)", cn)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Members")
    With Me.ComboBox1
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Member_Id"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're Query is just wrong. 'Except' doesn't exist in MS ACCESS.
You can easily avoid the usage of Except with the following structure:

```
 Select * 
 from tableA
 where NOT EXISTS
  ...
```

Or

```
 Select * 
 from tableA
 where NOT IN
  ...
```

In your Case (if M_Ids is the same type as Member_ID):

```
 Select [Member_Id] From Member_Details md 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (select [M_Ids] from Books_Issue WHERE [M_Ids] = md.[Member_ID])
```